# PHP+MySQL: compare rows in database to have percent of matching fields

Tags: mysql, database, matching

I have a small database with some users that they need to answer to 10 questions: I would like to compare male with female users and have back a percentage of the matching answers for each couple:

my db is a very simple one:

Table: USERS

```
ID_user(INT), name(VARCHAR), gender (M or F), answer1(VARCHAR), ..., answer10
```

I also created a table to store previous matching results (so I will not have a positive match two times by looking if the matching has already been stored in this table)

Table: MATCH

```
ID_match, ID_user(M), ID_user(F), match_date
```

EXAMPLE:

```
male1 answered:    1,2,3,1,2,3,4,3,2,3
male2 answered:    5,2,2,1,5,3,3,3,1,3

female 1 answered: 1,1,3,1,4,3,1,3,2,2
female 2 answered: 4,2,3,1,2,6,4,3,6,3
```

results:

```
match male1-female1 = 6
match male1-female2 = 7
match male2-female1 = 3
match male2-female2 = 4
```

I also need to send some email to who has the matching percent over 60%; and all this will be integrated in a wordpress website but this is a secondary problem :p

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have control over your database then the best approach is to redesign you database. The normalised version of this would have two tables one for the person's record and one for the answers (ID_answer(INT),user(INT),answer_number(INT),answer_chosen(INT)). You will find this problem much more solvable with a normalised database structure

Comment: In my first db idea there was many more tables such like: questions, answers, users, matched, etc

Comment: There are optimum designs for databases that result in maximum efficiency, flexibility and integrity for the data stored. The reason you should use two tables rather than one could be illustrated by the simple change to have 11 questions. In your design you would have to alter the table, whereas with two tables you wouldn't need to change anything. This process is called normalization and is worth reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do it in an ugly manner, with nested queries and self-joins

Inner query:

```
SELECT
   t1.ID_user AS user1, t2.ID_user AS user2
   t1.answer1 = t2.answer1 AS a1,
   t1.answer2 = t2.answer2 AS a2,
   ...
   t1.answer10 = t2.answer10 AS a10
FROM users AS t1
INNER JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id AND (t1.gender <> t2.gender)
```

This gives you a basic list of inter-person matches, with `0`/`1` values for the matches

You'd then wrap another query around this:

```
SELECT user1, user2, (a1 + a2 + .... + a10) AS matched_answers
FROM ( ... other query here ... ) AS q
WHERE matched_answers >= 6
ORDER BY matched_answers DESC
```

You sum up the answers from the subquery, sort descending, and return only the groupings where 6+ answers matched up.

And later on, if you decide to allow gay matches, you simply take the gender matching out of the join clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try asap your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

@marc-b
Hi, after many days I finally managed to work again on this table, my final working query (thanks to your suggestion) is:

```
SELECT
 t1.ID_user AS user1, t2.ID_user AS user2,
 ( (t1.r1 = t2.r1) + (t1.r2 = t2.r2) + (t1.r3 = t2.r3) + (t1.r4 = t2.r4) + (t1.r5 = t2.r5) + (t1.r6 = t2.r6) + (t1.r7 = t2.r7) + (t1.r8 = t2.r8) + (t1.r9 = t2.r9) + (t1.r10 = t2.r10) ) AS matched_answers,
 t1.r1 = t2.r1 AS a1,
 t1.r2 = t2.r2 AS a2,
 t1.r3 = t2.r3 AS a3,
 t1.r4 = t2.r4 AS a4,
 t1.r5 = t2.r5 AS a5,
 t1.r6 = t2.r6 AS a6,
 t1.r7 = t2.r7 AS a7,
 t1.r8 = t2.r8 AS a8,
 t1.r9 = t2.r9 AS a9,
 t1.r10 = t2.r10 AS a10
FROM a_answers AS t1
INNER JOIN a_answers AS t2 ON t1.ID_answer <> t2.ID_answer AND t1.gender <> t2.gender WHERE t1.gender = "f" HAVING matched_answers >= 6 ORDER BY user1, user2
```

and work like a charm

Thanks a lot